# Oauth Revoke access token only

Tags: http, authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm using OAuth 2.0 to log in users in my website. Just like any kind of website, e.g. Google, Asana, etc. .

What I would like to know is if there is a way to revoke ONLY the access token and not the refresh token when the user logs out.

This is what I do:

when a user logs in, I create a session and obtain the access token (and the refresh token if the user logs in for the first time). When the user logs out, I just invalidate the session but the access token is still valid.

Sure, the access token will invalidate after a while or when the user logs in the web app again but what I want to know is if the access token can be invalidated during the log out process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no generic answer to this question as the implementation of token revocation behavior wrt. related tokens is Authorization Server specific. Google will invalidate the refresh token together with the access token that is being revoked, other implementations may choose not to do so. Yet other implementations may not even offer a way to revoke access tokens at all.

For Google you can revoke the access token upon logout as described in https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke but it will also revoke the associated refresh token. You must then go through the authorization code flow again to get a new refresh token, which you could try with `prompt=none` to avoid the user being prompted.