# On revoking Google access token for a user, all the token granted to him across devices are getting invalidated

Tags: google-drive-api

From https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp, I come to know that -

To programmatically revoke a token, your application makes a request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke and includes the token as a parameter:

```
    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```

The token can be an access token or a refresh token. If the token is an access token and it has a corresponding refresh token, the refresh token will also be revoked.

Coming to my question –

I have a same Google user logged in on 2 devices (that means I have 2 sets of access/refresh tokens for same user for a particular client app)–

Machine 1 : Access token – A1, Refresh token – R1

Machine 2 : Access Token – A2, Refresh Token – R2

Now on machine 1, I revoked access through  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=A1, this invalidates {A1,R1} but what I am observing is that {A2,R2} are also getting invalidated.

Is this expected? How can I keep {A2,R2} validate?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526092/oauth-revoke-access-token-only?rq=1), Google will invalidate the refresh token together with the access token that is being revoked, other implementations may choose not to do so. Yet other implementations may not even offer a way to revoke access tokens at all.

> For Google you can revoke the access token upon logout as described in https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke but it will also revoke the associated refresh token. You must then go through the authorization code flow again to get a new refresh token, which you could try with prompt=none to avoid the user being prompted.

Comment: I want to invalidate both access token and refresh token {A1, R1} on machine 1 but I don't want to invalidate token set on another machine {A2, R2}.